# Get from youtube playlist video, with jQuery, api

Tags: jquery, json, api, youtube

Can somebody help me to suggest how can I get the play list from the youtube URL:

this is the URL :

http://www.youtube.com/CalgaryStampede1912

And I want to get the playlist or the first 2 videos from this video category with jQuery  .

Or there is some jQuery plugin for that ...

Thank You !!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query for a user's videos, which is what it sounds like you're trying to do. You can do it like this (see [API call here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html)) :

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&author=CalgaryStampede1912

And to access it in Javascript, you'll probably want Google's Javascript client library here: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-javascript-client/ That will probably be the easiest way to call it in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [RSSREADER](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/rssReader) plugin.